# Eloquent query problem using with() function for model relationship eager loading

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

How do write this eloquent query in Laravel so that it eager loads **with()** the relationship model in this example between a **User** model and **Profile** model?  I was trying to avoid 2 separate queries.

I feel I am close, but somethings not quite right.

```
$author = User::where('id', $id)->with('profile')->get();
```

The collection is returning the user details correctly.  But it's showing the **profile** relationship as null.

```
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "profile" => null
  ]
```

I believe I have things setup correctly with a **User** model and a **Profile** needed relationships.

User.php

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\AuthorProfile', 'user_id');
}
```

AuthorProfile.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming for AuthorProfile model table you have record with id of user it should be fine.

However you wrote:

> I was trying to avoid 2 separate queries.

Well, it's not true, if you have single record, eager loading won't help you at all. In this case 2 queries will be execute - no matter if you use eager loading or you won't.

Eager loading would help if you had multiple users and for each of them you wanted to load profile, but if you have single record it won't change anything.

Additionally instead of:

```
$author = User::where('id', $id)->with('profile')->get();
```

you should rather use:

```
$author = User::with('profile')->find($id);
```

because you expect here single user.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = User::with('profile')->find($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be like this.The User_id on the profile table and id on the user table

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\AuthorProfile', 'user_id','id');
}
```